# Can't create shortcut to All Users Startup

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using some basic code to be used in an installer for my program. To make my program run on startup, I am creating a .lnk in the All Users Startup folder.

The code I have works to create a shortcut, but I keep getting an error code 5 (priv error). I have tried right clicking and running this code as Admin, and it doesn't work, returns error code 5. I have also used the code to create shortcuts in other parts of the file system with no problem.

I have also used 3rd party programs, mainly "elevate.exe" to run my program, and that still doesn't work, it continues to return error code 5.

My question is, how can I use the code below to create a shortcut in the All User's Startup folder without UAC in my way?

```
 int main () 
 {

 CoInitialize(NULL);

 IShellLink* pShellLink = NULL;

 HRESULT hres;

 hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IShellLink,   (void**)&pShellLink);

  if (SUCCEEDED(hres))

  {
    pShellLink->SetPath("C:\\Windows\\System32\\testinstall\\test.exe");  // Path to the object we are referring to

    pShellLink->SetDescription("This is a test");

    pShellLink->SetIconLocation("C:\\Windows\\System32\\testinstall\\test.exe", 0);

    IPersistFile *pPersistFile;

    hres = pShellLink->QueryInterface(IID_IPersistFile, (void**)&pPersistFile);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hres))

    {
        hres = pPersistFile->Save(L"C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup", TRUE);

        pPersistFile->Release();
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Error 2" << endl;

        return 2;
    }

    pShellLink->Release();

    }

    else
    {

    cout << "Error 1" << endl;

    return 1;

    }

    cout << GetLastError ();

    _getch ();

    return 0;

    }
```

Comment: Out of interest, why not use an existing tool like NSIS?

Comment: The whole point of UAC is to prevent non-privileged programs from modifying things like All Users and system level configuration.

Comment: Mark B - As I stated, even when run as Admin (I've tried system also) UAC continues to block it.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit - I'll look into NSIS, but if this program cannot create a shortcut when running as system I don't see how NSIS is going to.